# Typescript errors - Argument of type and Parameter implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have following errors (solution is working):

> Argument of type 'string | object' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'IInterface1 | IInterface2'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to
>   type 'IInterface1 | IInterface2'. [2345]

and

> [ts] Parameter 'color' implicitly has an 'any' type. [7006]

Parts of code:

```
const createCollection = (jsonObject: object, namesObject: object): INameHex[] => {
  return Object.keys(jsonObject).map(itemKey => {
    return {
      name: namesObject[itemKey],
      hex: jsonObject[itemKey],
    }
  })
}

groupKey: string

const colors = createCollection(
  themeColors[groupKey], // <- this line gives error 2345
  colorsNames[groupKey],
).filter(color => !!color.name) // <- parameter color gives error 7006
```

The interesting part is that `themeColors[groupKey]` and `colorsNames[groupKey]` are of the same structure and type and yet only `themeColors[groupKey]`  gives an error. 
Any help in resolving those error much appreciated!

Comment: so, what is the definition of the createCollection function?

Comment: Added definition of createCollection

Comment: sorry but the definition of themeColors and colorsNames also needed to debug. If they are created like ```themeColors = new Array<object>()``` or ```themeColors = []```, it should be fine

Comment: themeColors[groupKey] is  Object object and it is for example   default: string
  [propName: string]: string

Comment: Please edit the code above to be a [mcve] that can be run in a [standalone TS compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), so that your errors can be reproduced by others.